# Azure Data Factory enable PolyBase

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

My account does not have right permission to create new schema on ADW, but if I put authorization end of Create command of T-SQL it works fine.

PolyBase requires creating table into the ADW, if I unbox the Allow PolyBase from Sink entire workflow is working.

Is there anyway to add property "authorization" into the ADF Copy Data?

Answer (score 0):

Does pre-copy script help ? You can try to create table by this script.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To use PolyBase, the user that loads data into SQL Data Warehouse must have "CONTROL" permission on the target database.
One way to achieve that is to add the user as a member of the db_owner role.